# What is the difference between UseHttpsRedirection and UseHsts

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I don't quite get the difference between `UseHsts` and `UseHttpsRedirection` in the configure section of the startup file in .net core. Could anyone explain?

Comment: One happens on browser side (HSTS), and the other on server side.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to the documentation you should use both together:

> We recommend all production ASP.NET Core web apps call:
>
> - The HTTPS Redirection Middleware (UseHttpsRedirection) to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.
> - UseHsts, HTTP Strict Transport Security Protocol (HSTS).

[ASP.NET Core Enforce HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The `.UseHttpsRedirection()` will issue HTTP response codes redirecting from http to https. The `.UseHsts()` will add the HSTS response [header which the client is supposed to obey.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts)

Comment: Both `UseHttpsRedirection` and `UseHsts` do nothing to block incoming http requests? So basically they are just instructions to the browser?

Comment: They do not block incoming requests. `UseHttpsRedirection` should issue a redirect from http to https. `UseHsts` is a header to remind the browser that when they come back to this site, skip the initial http request, and go directly to https. If you want to *block* http completely, you'd need to do that on your host (iis, apache, etc).

Answer (score 9):

`UseHsts` adds the `Strict-Transport-Security` header to the response, which informs the browser that the application must only be accessed with HTTPS.
After this declaration, compliant browsers should automatically convert any http request of the application into an HTTPS request.

`UseHttpsRedirection` causes an automatic redirection to HTTPS URL when an HTTP URL is received, in a way that forces a secure connection.

Once the first HTTPS secure connection is established, the `strict-security header` prevents future redirections that might be used to perform man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is a trivial concept. None of the answers already written does satisfy me. Here is my deductions after reading some articles.

---

HSTS is abbreviation of Strict-Transport-Security header in HTTP protocol.
It informs browsers that the site should only be accessed using HTTPS, and that any future attempts to access it using HTTP should automatically be converted to HTTPS. Using HSTS, the browser will call your application using HTTP only the very first time. The subsequent requests against the same domain will be made using the HTTPS protocol, even in the presence of a URL using the HTTP scheme.

The protection only applies after a user has visited the site at least once, relying on the principle of "trust on first use". The way this protection works is that a user entering or selecting a URL to the site that specifies HTTP, will automatically upgrade to HTTPS, without making an HTTP request, which prevents the HTTP man-in-the-middle attack from occurring.

HSTS is not guaranteed, it may not be supported by your client. It also requires at least one successful HTTPS request to establish the HSTS policy. HSTS is a client side performance optimization to avoid an extra request to the server.

UseHttpsRedirection middleware redirects incoming HTTP requests to HTTPS, ensuring that all communication between the client and server is encrypted.
It does redirect to https if properly configured. The risk is that the client may have sent sensitive data on that initial request. HSTS will prevent such leaks in the future, but cannot protect the first request.

I like answers on [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129273/whats-the-difference-between-using-hsts-and-doing-a-301-redirection) as well.